# Open Jquery-ui dialog in another <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, ejs

is it possible to initialize and open the jquery-ui dialog in a different "script" tag , like this :

> Specification : Working with EJS (Nodejs express templates)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#loginfailed").dialog({
            width: 500, autoOpen: false, resizable: false, draggable: false,
            modal: false 
        });


    });

</script>

//some html

 <% if (lengthQ1 == 0 && lengthQ2 == 0) { %>
     <script>
          $( "#loginfailed" ).text("User not exist");
         $( "#loginfailed" ).dialog("open");  
     </script>
    <% } else if (lengthQ1  == null  && lengthQ2 == null) { %>
     <script>
     </script>
    <% } else if (lengthQ1  > 0  || lengthQ2 > 0 && PasswordMatch != true) { %>
     <script>
          $( "#loginfailed" ).text("Wrong password");
         $( "#loginfailed" ).dialog("open");  
     </script>
    <% } %>
```

Actually, the dialog isn't showing and i can't undestand why.  when i move

```
$( "#loginfailed" ).dialog("open");
```

in the document.ready function it show me the dialog when the page load.

Assuming that the if statements and everything in it works (when replacing dialog with a simple

```
alert("wrong password"`)
```

its' working

Comment: It can be done. I would advise defining a constant variable with the dialog, so that you can reference in another script block or reinitialize it.

Comment: Personally, I would keep all my JS in one script block if possible. Is there a reason you are breaking up the script blocks?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot pass a variable between blocks, yet the dialog can be accessed. You can do something like (assuming the initial script block is in the head):

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#loginFailed").dialog({
    width: 500,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    modal: false 
  });
});
</script>
//some html
<% if (lengthQ1 == 0 && lengthQ2 == 0) { %>
  <script>
  $("#loginFailed").text("User not exist.").dialog("instance").open();  
  </script>
<% } else if (lengthQ1  == null  && lengthQ2 == null) { %>
  <script>
  // Do Nothing?
  </script>
<% } else if (lengthQ1  > 0  || lengthQ2 > 0 && PasswordMatch != true) { %>
  <script>
  $("#loginFailed").text("Wrong password").dialog("instance").open();  
  </script>
<% } %>
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/drL16vyc/

More Details: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/widget-method-invocation/

> Under the hoods, every instance of every widget is stored on the element using `jQuery.data()`. To retrieve the instance object, call `jQuery.data()` using the widget's full name as the key.
>
> In jQuery UI 1.11, the new instance() method will make this process even easier.
>
> `$( ".selector" ).dialog( "instance" ).close();`

Now, reading between the lines, I am assuming you have some sort of login form and are posting data back to itself for authentication. Why not do this via AJAX?

```
<script>
var $lfDiag;
$(function() {
  $lfDiag = $("#loginFailed").dialog({
    width: 500,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    modal: false 
  });
  $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    var myFormData = {
      api: "json"
    };
    var loginFailed = true;
    $(this).find("input").each(function(ind, el){
      myFormData[$(el).attr("id")] = $(el).val();
    });
    $.post(url, myFormData, function(results){
      if(results.error.length){
        $lfDiag.text(results.error).dialog("open");
      } else {
        loginFailed = false;
      }
    });
    return !loginFailed;
  });
});
</script>
```

Now this setup will take a bit of adjustment. You will need a conditional form handler that can authenticate the submitted details against your database. The condition is that if `api` is set to `json` it it will send back json data. This could be like:

```
{
  success: true
}
```

Or:

```
{
  success: false,
  error: "User does not exist."
}
```

If the posted data does not include the `api` data, then the script should process the login like normal. I'm assuming this is logging the user in and setting some session variables.